# Locomotive Content not visible even when visible in CSS dev tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, locomotive-scroll

Using Locomotive Smooth scroll, Scroll works fine, the issue occurs while scrolling back to the top, the header doesn't get visible even when the CSS inspect has opacity 1, so not sure why the header is not getting visible.

Another strange behaviour, header gets visible if I untick and tick back any CSS on the dev console or If I do select all from the keyword then the header gets visible, If I resize the browser then the header gets visible.

let options = {
el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
smooth: true,
getSpeed: true,
getDirection: true,
reloadOnContextChange: true
}

const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll(options);

header have data-scroll  data-scroll-section

Answer (score 0):

This is happening  after chrome  update
just add this line in css should work

```
html.has-scroll-smooth {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```